# Cross Site Lookup Column

Tags: sharepoint

In present project we have a requirement like, access one site collection column to another site collection.
I thought this can be achived by creating custom field, to access the cross site collection lookup column, I don't kanow any other ways are there to access the cross site collection lookup column in SharePoint 2010.

Could you please guide me on this how to implement this kind of requirement.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[How to use the lookup field across different site collections](http://stefan-stanev-sharepoint-blog.blogspot.com/2009/04/how-to-use-lookup-field-across.html):

> The question is - is it possible to set a lookup list which is in a site in a different site collection. The answer is - yes, I just created a small POC which demonstrates how this works - still there're some limitations - the site collection containing the lookup list should be in the same content database in which the list with the lookup field is.